# Servicio RestFul JSON

Tags: c#, json, rest, restful

Estoy realizando un servicio restful, me devuelve datos como json pero pero dentro de un xml y **solo quiero json**. anexo imagen de como se ve el resultado. y mi código. quiero quitar lo resaltado en amarillo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
namespace WcfServiceWOM
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetDataUsingMethod(string rut, string idCliente, string top);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData/rut={rut}&idCliente={idCliente}&top={top}")]
        List<ItemOmniVM> GetDataUsingURI(string rut, string idCliente, string top);
    }
}

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetDataUsingMethod(string rut, string idCliente, string top)
        {
            List<ItemOmniVM> list = new ItemOmniDao().read(rut, idCliente, top);

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
            return json;
        }
        public List<ItemOmniVM> GetDataUsingURI(string rut, string idCliente, string top)
        {
            List<ItemOmniVM> list = new ItemOmniDao().read(rut, idCliente, top);

            return list;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hola Alexandra, por prederminada el servicio WCF retorna como XML, tal como se ve en la imagen que has subido. Pero si deseas que retorne como JSON(RESTFul) tienes que agregar algunos atributos al metodo, revisa el siguiente enlace que esta explicado: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estaría faltando un adorno a los atributos de tu WebGet. Quedaría de esta manera:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetDataUsingMethod(string rut, string idCliente, string top);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetData/rut={rut}&idCliente={idCliente}&top={top}")]
    List<ItemOmniVM> GetDataUsingURI(string rut, string idCliente, string top);
}
```

Espero resulte útil

Comment: Muy util, adicional agregué algunos cambios en el web config con el comentario de @waimaku y funcionó muchas gracias.